# Is there a way to log everything that happens in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I'd need to keep a record of everything that happens with some repositories. By default I can keep a record of merging and commits, but I'd need a record of cloning, pulls, authentication, etc.

Is there a way to keep this logged somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Cloning, pulling, and authenticating are not part of a repository's history or state - all of that data is intentionally not tracked or pushed around by Mercurial.

In fact, Mercurial doesn't handle this behavior itself, it offloads this (particularly authentication) to the web server handling such requests.  What you can do is look at the logs the server records.  How this is tracked is very much server specific, but essentially you'd look at the access logs and see what is being requested.

Mercurial provides a lightweight web server `hg serve` for handling limited numbers of requests, and you can configure where both access and error logs are written to by this server with the `-A` and `-E` flags respectively.  See `hg help serve` for more.

You could play with Mercurial's [hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) and maybe log clones and pulls via that method, but authentication is completely transparent to Mercurial, so logging that must come from the server.

Comment: I didn't know about hooks, I'm trying to create one that suits the purpose, but haven't found the way to reference the user of the mercurial process. For example, I was able to create a hook that does something when a pull or push has been made, but I would like to log who made that pull/push. Which variable references the user? if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

How are people accessing the repository.  If it's over ssh you could easily log the command line that comes in via ssh.  If it's over HTTP you can use your weblogs as a pretty fair record.

Mozilla has an open source 'pushlog' (example: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/pushloghtml ) that they use to record all writes.  You could probably easily tweak that code to record all reads too.

Comment: Ammm I'm quite new at this, I think they are accessing via SCM Manager, could that be correct? I enabled DEBUG log in SCM, but still won't log something useful.

Comment: I don't know SCM Manager -- it's not part of git of Mercurial, so this becomes entirely a SCM Manager question.  Since SCM Manager's homepage boasts that it uses a build in web server instead of one where we could easily add this logging you'll have to ask them.  Maybe tag it as such and hope they're active.